# Google Drive API search with "mimeType contains" query doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am working with Google Drive v3 and I am trying to get all files which are related to following categories:

- files which are not Google Documents (mime type doesn't start from "application/vnd.google-apps."), for example "text/plain", "image/bmp" etc.
- Google Spreadsheets (mime type is "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet")

I want get all these files with single request.

Files from first category can be get with following sub-query:
`not mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.'`

Sub-query for second category: `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'`

As result I unite these parts with `or` operator and then with query for parent folder id:
`'<parentId>' in parents and (mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' or not mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.')`

But it doesn't work. It returns only Google Spreadsheet files.
I tried to execute queries for both file categories separately and they work fine:

`'<parentId>' in parents and (mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet')` returns all Google Spreadsheets

and

`'<parentId>' in parents and (not mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.')` returns all not-Google Drive formats.
`

As experiment I checked another cases (a bit simplified):

- `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' or mimeType = 'text/plain'` - returns spreadsheets+texts, correct
- `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' or mimeType contains 'text/plain'` - returns spreadsheets only, incorrect
- `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' or not mimeType = 'text/plain'` - returns spreadsheets only, incorrect (I have images in the folder also)
- `mimeType contains 'text/plain'` - returns texts, correct

Part of my code for files requesting (with parentId replaced, of course):

```
Drive.Files.List filesRequest = service
      .files()
      .list()
      .setFields("files(id, name)")
      .setQ("'<parentId>' in parents " +
              "and (mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' " +
                "or not mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.')");
    FileList result = filesRequest.execute();
    List<File> files = result.getFiles();
```

Used dependencies versions: google-api-services-drive from v3-rev162-1.23.0 to v3-rev173-1.25.0, JDK 1.8.0-91.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to retrieve all files except for Google related files except for Google Spreadsheet.

  > - files which are not Google Documents (mime type doesn't start from "application/vnd.google-apps."), for example "text/plain", "image/bmp" etc.
  > - Google Spreadsheets (mime type is "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet")
- You want to achieve this by a single request with one search query.

If my understanding is correct, how about this query? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

From your situation and your tested sample queries, how about the query for ignoring all mimeTypes of Google Docs except for `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`? All mimeTypes of Google related files can be seen at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types).

#### Sample search query:

```
'<parentId>' in parents and (mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.audio' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.document' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.drawing' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.file' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.form' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.map' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.photo' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.presentation' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.script' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.site' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.unknown' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.video' and mimeType!='application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk')
```

or

```
'<parentId>' in parents and not (mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.audio' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.drawing' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.file' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.form' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.map' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.photo' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.presentation' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.script' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.site' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.unknown' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.video' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk')
```

or

```
'<parentId>' in parents and not (mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.audio' or mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.d' or mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.f' or mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.m' or mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.p' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.script' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.site' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.unknown' or mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.video')
```

#### Note:

- If there are files more than 1000 by searching with the query, in order to retrieve all files, `pageToken` is required to be used. At this time, the multiple requests are required to be done. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Supported MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes, it is working solution. But anyway I don't understand why API doesn't work for requests, posted in question. Is it correct but undocumented behavior or a some API issue?

Comment: @Dmitrii Vitiiuk Thank you for replying. About `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.###' or not mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.'`, in the case of Google Docs which are the files (Document, Spreadsheet and so on), only the files of `mimeType='###'` are retrieved. But at `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' or not mimeType contains 'application/vnd.google-apps.'`, the folders and all files except for Google Docs. From this situation, I thought that it might be a bug. So I proposed the above query as the workaround. If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Dmitrii Vitiiuk Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.